# How to implement an AngularJS slider where 3 sliders shares between a single distributable value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement in AngularJS 3 sliders that represents 3 different attributes
that shares a common max amount of distributable skill points.

How do I do this in angularJS
There are a lot of examples about a lot of elements in AngularJS but almost none using sliders beyond their original usage.

e.g.

```
 Distributable Skill Points = 100

 strength      0------------------[]--------------- 100   (45)
 agility       0------[]--------------------------- 100   (10)
 intelligence  0------------[]--------------------- 100   (20)

                                          remaining pts   (15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing based on the context, this functionality will probably needed to be persisted therefore I suggest the use of a service. With a service you can manage the max points available as well as each of the different skills.

```
angular.module('Skills', [])
    .factory('SkillsService', function() {
         var service = {};
         service.max = 100;
         service.skills = {'strength': 0, 
                           'agility': 0, 
                           'intelligence': 0};

         //The following functions would probably be $http calls if this data needs to be persisted
         service.updateSkill = function(skill, value) {
              service.skills[skill] = value;
         };

         service.pointsRemaining = function() {
              var total = 0;
              angular.forEach(service.skills, function(key, value) {
                   total += value;
              };
              return service.max - total;
         };

         return service;
    });
```

Having this service means you can use this in many places and the data will be in one spot.

Your view and controller can look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="SkillsController as skillCtrl">
    <slider ng-change="skillCtrl.updateSkill(skill, sliderValue)" 
            ng-repeat="skill as skillCtrl.skills"
            ng-disabled="skillCtrl.pointsRemaining() === 0"></slider>
</div>
```

keep in mind this is just a proof of concept. Its more the logic thats needed since I am unsure which slider module you are using or what your project requirements actually are.

```
angular.module('Skills')
    .controller('SkillsController', function(SkillsService) {
        var self = this;

        self.updateSkill = function(skill, sliderValue) {
            SkillsService.updateSkill(skill, sliderValue);
        };

        self.pointsRemaining = function() {
            return SkillsService.pointsRemaining();
        };
    });
```

Comment: Yes sir that is exactly my question.  Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twothumbsticks/nf15zw1j/3/) Is there a simpler way to implement your answer to my code without using modules and services?  Or is there a better slider directive that I could use?  Sorry if Im very confused I am just a newbie to angular sir.

Answer (score 1):

Check: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfzcw2jr/1/).

A directive is your natural choice. Define a directive with an attribute `max`. This value is two-way binded, which can be shared among multiple `instances` of the directive.

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('JoyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.max = 10;
})
    .directive('skills', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            max: '=',
            value: '@'
        },
        template: '<span ng-repeat="i in range"=>{{(i==value) ? value : "-"}}</span>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.range = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.max; i++) {
                $scope.range.push(i);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl">
    <div skills max="max" value="2"></div>
    <div skills max="max" value="4"></div>
    <div skills max="max" value="6"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively (may be better): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfzcw2jr/3/).

Store the value `max` inside some `constant`, then inject it into the directive. It avoids passing in the parameter `max` every time.